# How do I root my LG Optimus F3 on Linux?

Tags: android, elementary

Also, can someone please tell me where to find the linux drivers for my phone, so that I can root my phone? Do I even need a specific set of drivers if I am running linux?

I am using Elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: Rooting your Android device voids its warranty. You can however claim the warranty back by unrooting the device. I or the developer of this rooting tool is not responsible for any damage that your device might have to incur during this process. Proceed at your own risk.*

1. Open terminal(Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter(in terminal) **adb**(connect your phone first and enable USB debugging)
2. Enter **fastboot**(in terminal). If you get some kind of error(after first or second step), go to 2.1, else go to 3

   2.1 Enter the following in the terminal:

   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

   Press enter, then enter the following:

   > sudo apt-get update &&
   >   sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot

   Press y and then enter.
3. Download [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2061653&d=1371919929) and unzip it.
4. Run run.sh inside motochopper folder